# licensing returning not licensed

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am using the market licensing in my app.
Recently iv been getting reports from people that after resetting their phones they can install the app but when they load it. It says its not licensed. Is this Google's fault?

Its very damaging because I don't know how I can help people.

Comment: Is it *some* people or *all* people? What Policy have you implemented or used?

Comment: Not all no, just people who have reset their devices. I'm just using the serverManagedPolicy, Should I make my own policy?

Comment: No, it's easier to make mistakes in your own policy. Then, I can't think of anything more than my current answer: these people reset their phone and don't use the same Google account than before. But in that case, all licensed applications would be broken, not only yours.

Answer (score 0):

To be valid, the request must be on the *same* device with the *same Google account*.